# XE5 RestClient Library issues

Tags: delphi, rest, delphi-xe5

I have created a FMX Windows app that connects to a web server to obtain REST data. I have been using the REST Client, Response, Request and ResponseDataAdapter and have connected that to a Client Data Set. I have then connected the Datasets to a string grid through live bindings.  I have done this for 2 different string grids with no problems at all,  And then I come to the very last request I want to make and I am getting some very strange behaviour.  I set everything up in a data module and did an execute of the RestRequest in the IDE and got the content I expected in the RESTResponse.  I then activated the RESTResponseAdapter and ClientDataset.  The clientdata set was populated and I was able to add the fielddefs through the ide by just going to add fields.

I have a timer setup on the app to update the string grids etc,,,  Works fine for two string grids.  However on the last one all I ever get on the StringGrid is the data that I originally fetched while in the IDE. I assumed this could be due to some caching on the clientdataset so I put a memo on the form and after each request execute I posted the response content to the memo.... The bizarre thing is that I occasionally get the response the server is currently sending back (Verified by going to the webserver through Chrome) but sometimes the Response Content is the data that I originally requested when I set it up in the IDE. So I went back to the IDE and cleared the response data from the Rest Response.  Tried again and get the same... I get the expected result sometimes and other times I get the response that I originally got in the IDE yesterday.  So then I thought perhaps the webserver was sending it back.  So have run the same REST request through the webserver and never get back the data that the restresponse is showing...

The code below fires on my timer. The top two sets of code are working fine the last one is the buggy one.

```
  restDataModule.adapterOperators.ClearDataSet;
  restDataModule.cdsOperators.Close;
  restDataModule.responseOperators.Content.Empty;
  restDataModule.reqOnlineOperators.ClearBody;
  restDataModule.reqOnlineOperators.Execute;
  restDataModule.cdsOperators.Open;

  restDataModule.adapterStats.ClearDataSet;
  restDataModule.cdsStats.Close;
  restDataModule.responseOperatorStats.Content.Empty;
  restDataModule.reqOperatorStats.ClearBody;
  restDataModule.reqOperatorStats.Execute;
  restDataModule.cdsStats.Open;

  try
  restDataModule.adapterChats.ClearDataSet;
  restDataModule.cdsChats.Close;
  restDataModule.responseChats.Content.Empty;
  restDataModule.reqChats.ClearBody;
  restDataModule.reqChats.Execute;
  restDataModule.cdsChats.Open;
  except on E: Exception do
    // ignore
    memo1.Lines.Add('Failed!')
  end;
  memo1.Lines.Add(restDataModule.responseChats.Content);
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution was to add a Parameter to the RestClient with the following settings:-
Kind = pkHTTPHEADER
Name = Cache-Control
Value = no-cache

Simple but elusive